# how to add a form to a build array

Tags: 8, forms

I am creating a custom module that has the following as the build:

```
$build = array(

          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => $html,
          '#attached' => array(

             'library' => array('pup_viewfiles/sortfiles_libraries'),
            ),
        );

    return $build;
```

I have a Form that I get with the following line :

```
$form=\Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm(pup_viewfiles\pager),
```

The question is how can I incorporate this form into the build ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getForm()` returns a render array, and a render array can have other render arrays as children, so:

```
$build = [
    'form' => $form,
    ...
];
```